# Error when installing wsclient plugin

Tags: griffon

I am using griffon 0.9.4 and I wanted to install the last version of the wsclient plugin 0.4.2. I am getting the following error:

```
Welcome to Griffon 0.9.4 - http://griffon.codehaus.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0 
Griffon home is set to: /usr/local/griffon/griffon-0.9.4 

Base Directory: /Users/alex/Documents/workspace/projetname/ImportDataConsole 
Resolving dependencies... 
Dependencies resolved in 650ms. 
Running script /usr/local/griffon/griffon-0.9.4/scripts/InstallPlugin.groovy 
Environment set to development 
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/classes 
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/plugin-classes 
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/test classes/shared 
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/test-resources 
Resolving plugin wsclient. Please wait... 

Installing zip /Users/alex/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/wsclient/zips/wsclient-0.4.2-jar.zip... ... 
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/plugins/wsclient-0.4.2 
    [unzip] Expanding: /Users/alex/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.griffon.plugins/wsclient/zips/wsclient-0.4.2-jar.zip into /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/plugins/wsclient-0.4.2 
Installed plugin wsclient-0.4.2 to location /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/plugins/wsclient-0.4.2. ... 
Resolving plugin JAR dependencies ... 
Plugin license for wsclient-0.4.2 is 'Apache Software License 2.0' 
Executing wsclient-0.4.2 plugin post-install script ... 
Error installing plugin: No such property: config for class: Script1 
    [delete] Deleting directory /Users/alex/.griffon/0.9.4/projects/ImportDataConsole/plugins/wsclient-0.4.2
```

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wsclient requires an update to properly work with 0.9.4 as the expected config variable (by scripts/_Install.groovy) is no longer available at buildtime as before. We'll push a new version shortly.

Comment: Version 0.5 of the plugin is now available. It fixes the problem and adds a Java friendly API for calling dynamic methods, just like the other remoting plugins :-)